# An exercise on contour Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Hello dear mathematicians:
I've got this exercise and honestly I didn't find any clue about it and I couldn't solve it if anyone can help me I would be thankful for him :

For what contour $C$ , we have  $∫dz/(z^2+4) = 0$

$1- C : z = 1$

$2- C : z-2i = 2$

$3- C : z+2i = 2$

Comment: Hello there, when asking a question try to implement latex. Here is a guide on how to use Latex : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: When you typed Counter in the title, did you mean Contour?

Comment: Have you any idea what the contour integration is? Please check if there are vertical bars ($||$) in the equations of the contours (1,2,3).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Cauchy's theorem if you take as contour a circle centered at the origin, say, of radius $1$.  For the poles are at $\pm2i$, and thus outside the contour.